# .htaccess is not working on Zend server on Windows

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-server

I am a beginner to MVC framework in PHP and also to .htaccess file. I use Zend server on Windows OS.

My code in .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The line `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` is enabled in my httpd.conf file.

the .htaccess not working on my server

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

To activate htaccess, check your configuration files and ensure you have the following or similar lines:

```
# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```